# Primefaces MindMap Hierarchy

Tags: primefaces, mindmap

I was playing around with the primefaces MindMap component and I saw that the MindMap component isn´t rendering any nodes beyond the 1st hierarchy level. For example : It only displays the Root + Node1, but not Node2, which is a child of Node1.

I know that I can click that node and use the lazy loading mechanism to "zoom in", but I would rather have an overview picture of all the different nodes.

Is there any way to display all child nodes of all nodes together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve given up on that.
It seems that the primefaces MindMap component is only working lazily and only displays 2 hierarchy levels.